# Can't extend C partition with unallocated space. Due to a recovery partition is next to C drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, disk-space

I just upgraded my laptop with a 2TB ssd by cloning the old 256G SSD. However I found the C drive volume can not be extended due to a "Recovery partition" is standing in between the unallocated volume and C drive. There is no option while right click this "Recovery partition".
Can someone give me an advise what I can do to extent my C drive Volume?

[image: Screen shot of disk manager]

Comment: Thank Romhound, I found that answer too but in that thread his D drive can be copied, in my case the "Recovery Portion" can not.

Comment: Why? Because you either need to move it or delete it and then recreate it. There isn't another solution to your described problem. You can use [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1256334/) as a solution but the suggested tool does the same thing as GParted. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/972227/) is a third duplicate candidate. The solution to the original duplicate flag, and this question, is identical.  The partition must be moved, to another part of the disk, in order to extend the system partition.

Comment: I see. You are right, looks like I have to borrow a third party software to move the "recovery partition". Thanks!